# Sorting columns with pandas / xslxwriter after adding formulas

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have my dataframe with few columns, that's actually irrelevant to this problem, but I wanted to sort my columns in specific order.

Now, the issue is that I have a bunch of formulas that refer to excel tables (that I'm creating with xslxwriter worksheet.add_table), like for example:

```
planned_units = '=Table1[@[Spend]]/Table1[@[CP]]'
```

So if I will add those formulas by simply adding a column in pandas:

```
df['newformula'] = planned_units
```

it won't work, I think because I added a formula that references a table before actually adding a table. So sorting those columns before adding formulas won't work because:

- I'm adding formulas later (after creating a table) but I also want to sort columns that I just added
- if I'm adding formulas referencing an excel table before add_table, then those formulas
  won't work in excel

It seems that xslxwriter doesn't allow me to sort columns in any way (maybe im wrong?) so I don't see any possibility of sorting columns after I have my final 'product' (after adding all columns with formulas).

It's still better to have working formulas instead of sorted columns, but I will happily welcome any ideas on how to sort them at this point.

thanks!

PS Code example:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter


# simple dataframe with 3 columns

input_df = pd.DataFrame({'column_a': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
                         'column_b': ['red', 'white', 'blue'],
                         'column_c': ['a', 'e', 'i'],
                         })

output_file = 'output.xlsx'

# formula I want to add
column_concatenation = '=CONCATENATE(Table1[@[column_a]], " ", Table1[@[column_b]])'

# now if adding formulas with pandas would be possible, I would do it like this:

# input_df['concatenation'] = column_concatenation
# but its not possible since excel gives you errors while opening!

# adding excel table with xlsxwriter:

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_file)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Sheet with formula")

# here I would change column order only IF formulas added with pandas would work! so no-no
'''
desired_column_order = ['columnB', 'concatenation', 'columnC', 'columnA']
input_df = input_df[desired_column_order]
'''
data = input_df

worksheet.add_table('A1:D4', {'data': data.values.tolist(),
                              'columns': [{'header': c} for c in data.columns.tolist()] +
                                         [{'header': 'concatenation',
                                           'formula': column_concatenation}
                                          ],
                              'style': 'Table Style Medium 9'})

workbook.close()
```

Now before workbook.close() I'd love to use that table 'desired_column_order' to re-order my columns after I've added formulas.

thanks:)

Comment: Could you create an example about a dataframe with which we could solve your problem?

Comment: right, sorry about that. Added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are two issues here: sorting and the table formula.

Sorting is something that Excel does at runtime, in the Excel application and it isn't a property of, or something that can be triggered in, the file format. Since XlsxWriter only deals with the file format it cannot do any sorting. However, the data can be sorted in Python/Pandas prior to writing it with XlsxWriter.

The formula issue is due to the fact that Excel had an original `[#This Row]` syntax (Excel 2007) and a later `@` syntax (Excel 2010+). See the XlsxWriter docs on [Working with Worksheet Tables - Columns](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html#columns):

> The Excel 2007 style `[#This Row]` and Excel 2010 style `@` structural references are supported within the formula. However, other Excel 2010 additions to structural references aren’t supported and formulas should conform to Excel 2007 style formulas.

So basically you need to use the Excel 2007 syntax, since that is what is stored in the file format, even if Excel displays the Excel 2010+ syntax externally.

When you add formulas via the `add_table()` method XlsxWriter does the conversion for you but if you add the formulas in another way, such as via Pandas, you need to use the Excel 2007 syntax. So instead of a formula like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(Table1[@[column_a]], " ", Table1[@[column_b]])
```

You need to add this:

```
=CONCATENATE(Table1[[#This Row],[column_a]], " ", Table1[[#This Row],[column_b]])
```

(You can see why the moved to the shorter syntax in later Excel versions.)

Then your program will work as expected:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

input_df = pd.DataFrame({'column_a': ['x', 'y', 'z'],
                         'column_b': ['red', 'white', 'blue'],
                         'column_c': ['a', 'e', 'i'],
                         })

output_file = 'output.xlsx'

column_concatenation = '=CONCATENATE(Table1[[#This Row],[column_a]], " ", Table1[[#This Row],[column_b]])'

input_df['concatenation'] = column_concatenation


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(output_file)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Sheet with formula")

desired_column_order = ['column_b', 'concatenation', 'column_c', 'column_a']
input_df = input_df[desired_column_order]
data = input_df

# Make the columns wider for clarity.
worksheet.set_column(0, 3, 16)

worksheet.add_table('A1:D4', {'data': data.values.tolist(),
                              'columns': [{'header': c} for c in data.columns.tolist()] +
                                         [{'header': 'concatenation'}],
                              'style': 'Table Style Medium 9'})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]